# Adapt jQuery progress goal meter to include pending meter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to adapt the GoalMeter jQuery plugin to include a pending meter that can be displayed alongside the progress meter. I have created a CodePen and made some adaptations that can be viewed here: http://codepen.io/mikehermary/pen/xwEypo

```
update: function goalMeter_update(options) {
        if (typeof options === "object") {
            this.extendOptions(options);
        }

        // Get ze values
        this.goalAmount = this.getGoalAmount();
        this.progressAmount = this.getProgressAmount();
        this.pendingAmount = this.getPendingAmount();

        // Apply some math to this stuff.
        this.progressPercentageAmount = Math.min(
            Math.round(
                this.progressAmount / this.goalAmount * 1000
            ) / 10, 100
        ); //make sure we have 1 decimal point :)

        // figure out the new width/height
        this.newCSS[ this.isHorizontal ? "width" : "height" ] = this.progressPercentageAmount + "%";

        // render stuff. Yeah.
        this.render();

        // Apply some math to this stuff.
        this.pendingPercentageAmount = Math.min(
            Math.round(
                this.pendingAmount / this.goalAmount * 1000
            ) / 10, 100
        ); //make sure we have 1 decimal point :)

        // figure out the new width/height
        this.newCSS[ this.isHorizontal ? "width" : "height" ] = this.pendingPercentageAmount + "%";

        // render stuff. Yeah.
        this.render();

    },
```

This is the function that controls the meters and their vertical heights. As you can see in the CodePen example, the pending meter is overriding the donated meter. How can I make each meter independent?

Answer (score 0):

After some minor head scratching and trial and error, I have figured it out. The problem was solved by changing **newCSS** to **progressCSS** and **pendingCSS** for the horizontal or vertical display of the meter, then removing the first **this.render** function call. After these changes, the meters work and animate independently of each other.

I then figured out the z-indexes for each meter would need to switch, depending on which value was lower. If the progress value was lower, then it would need a higher z-index than pending and vice versa. I have attached the updated function from my previous example to show my changes.

```
update: function goalMeter_update(options) {
        if (typeof options === "object") {
            this.extendOptions(options);
        }

        // Get the values
        this.goalAmount = this.getGoalAmount();
        this.progressAmount = this.getProgressAmount();
        this.pendingAmount = this.getPendingAmount();

        // Apply some math to this stuff.
        this.progressPercentageAmount = Math.min(
            Math.round(
                this.progressAmount / this.goalAmount * 1000
            ) / 10, 100
        ); //make sure we have 1 decimal point :)

        // figure out the new width/height
        this.progressCSS[ this.isHorizontal ? "width" : "height" ] = this.progressPercentageAmount + "%";

        // Apply some math to this stuff.
        this.pendingPercentageAmount = Math.min(
            Math.round(
                this.pendingAmount / this.goalAmount * 1000
            ) / 10, 100
        ); //make sure we have 1 decimal point :)

        // figure out the new width/height
        this.pendingCSS[ this.isHorizontal ? "width" : "height" ] = this.pendingPercentageAmount + "%";

        // Set the z-index values
        if (this.progressAmount > this.pendingAmount) {
            this.progressCSS[ "z-index" ] = "1";
        }
        if (this.progressAmount < this.pendingAmount) {
            this.pendingCSS[ "z-index" ] = "1";
        }

        // render stuff. Yeah.
        this.render();

    },
```

I hope this may be helpful to anyone looking to achieve the same results with this plugin or jQuery in general.